# Kotlin - Filter/Map from two Collections

Tags: collections, kotlin

Is it possible to filter and map two Collections based on desired criteria match like the following:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val selectedDates = listOf("2018-08-12", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-14")

    val expenses = listOf(Expense("Food", "2018-08-12"),
    Expense("Transportation", "2018-08-15"),
    Expense("Misc.", "2018-08-13"),
     Expense("Uber", "2018-08-12"),
    Expense("Clothing", "2018-08-16"))

    val listOfExpensesInSelectedDate = mutableListOf<Expense>()

    for (date in selectedDates){
        listOfExpensesInSelectedDate.addAll(expenses.filter { it.date==date })

    }
    println(listOfExpensesInSelectedDate)

}

data class Expense(
        val expense:String,
        val date: String
)
```

Provided the given code above, I am trying to return a list of Expenses that match with the dates from another list of Strings.  In the example above, I have used both for Loop and filter function to get my desired result.  But is it possible to avoid the for loop and filter and map both the Collections in single line of code?

Answer (score 8):

You could just use `in` to filter:

```
val listOfExpensesInSelectedDate = expenses.filter { it.date in selectedDates }
```

**Edit**: since hotkey posted the comment about optimal solution, I have tried this in my pc and anyone interested can try it too:

**(1st)** my answer as was posted:

```
val start = Date().time
for (i in 1..10000) {
    val listOfExpensesInSelectedDate = expenses.filter { it.date in selectedDates }
}
val end= Date().time

println(end - start)
```

> Average time result: 26ms (23ms-35ms)

**(2nd)** my answer with the hotkey's suggestion to use a set:

```
val start = Date().time
for (i in 1..10000) {
    val expSet = selectedDates.toSet()
    val listOfExpensesInSelectedDate = expenses.filter { it.date in expSet }
}
val end= Date().time

println(end - start)
```

> Average time result: 70ms (50ms-86ms)

**(3d)** hotkey's answer:

```
val start = Date().time
for (i in 1..10000) {
    val groups = expenses.groupBy { it.date }
    val listOfExpensesInSelectedDate = selectedDates.flatMap { groups[it].orEmpty() }
}
val end= Date().time

println(end - start)
```

> Average time result: 100ms (74ms-150ms)

Comment: wow thanks. This is the most concise solution I have found so far

Comment: @dey this is **my** answer and the communication with OP is mine. No need for inbetween delegates. Delete your comment

Comment: Note that it is not an optimal solution since it will iterate over `seectedDates` each time to check the predicate. To improve it, convert `selectedDates` to a set.

Comment: @hotkey the iteration does not vanish with a set. It could be worse since the set is unordered.

Comment: @mTak, most sets have constant, O(1) time for a `contains` check, whereas lists do that with O(n) worst case. A test with large `selectedDates` would show that.

Comment: @hotkey I did simple tests with the proposed by the OP lists. See my edited answer.

Comment: @user8959091 it would shows: `Type inference failed` using keywords `in` inside `.filter { it.name in list }`

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify and optimize your code by first grouping `expenses` by the `date` and then selecting and merging the groups that have their key in the `selectedDates`, like this:

```
val selectedDates = listOf("2018-08-12", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-14")
val expenses: List<Expense> = TODO("content omitted")

val groups = expenses.groupBy { it.date }
val listOfExpensesInSelectedDate = selectedDates.flatMap { groups[it].orEmpty() }
```

See: [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html), [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html)

Comment: It gives the following error:

Error:(20, 54) Kotlin: Type inference failed: inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.flatMap(transform: (T) -> Iterable<R>): List<R>
cannot be applied to
receiver: List<String>  arguments: ((String) -> List<Expense>?)

Comment: @Econ_newbie, sorry, fixed the example by adding a fallback in case the key is missing: `groups[it].orEmpty()`.